# How to display images from other places in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am fairly new in Django and developing a book recommendation system using Django and PostgreSQL. I have my dataset with some field that also keeps corresponding book images URL (not the images itself) where images reside in other places, not in my static files or database. i want to access that images online and display them in my Django template here is how I tried to do but didn't work and doesn't access the image.

```
<img src= {{ book.image_url.url }} style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%"  alt="">
```

and also tried this:

```
<img src="{{ book.image_url.url }}" style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%"  alt="">
```

where book is dictionary and images_url is simply a url string for image residing somewhere in the web.
can you help me out how to access this string of url on the web and display it on django template ?

Answer (score 0):

For urls, you want to use a different template tag. Try this:

```
<img src="{% url book.image_url.url %}" style="display:block;" width="100%" height="100%"  alt="">
```

Comment: i got this error: Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value: 
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

Comment: Sounds like there might be a bug in your views.py file?

Comment: it works if I use static images, there is no but in views.py